# When using jQuery's ".nextAll()", how would i make "$(this)" equal the current element?

Tags: jquery

im trying to get an element, then every element after that make the placeholder attribute of **#taskid** the current value - 1

this is what im currently working with:

```
$(this).nextAll('div').find('#taskid').attr('placeholder', ((parseInt($(this)
    .find('#taskid').attr('placeholder')) - 1).toString()))
```

html:

```
<div id="i0HYh" class="task" select="yes" style="background-color: rgb(240, 239, 255);">
  <input type="text" name="taskid" placeholder="1" readonly="" id="taskid">
  <input type="text" name="email1" placeholder="sdf" readonly="">
  <input type="text" name="taskproxy" id="esfes" placeholder="N/A" readonly="">
  <div id="headlessbox">
    <p>t</p>
  </div>
  <input type="text" name="status" placeholder="Idle" readonly="">
</div>
```

The above jquery line works, it just changes the placeholder value to the first elements value - 1

for example, if the first elements value was 1, the rest of them would be 0

example of the placeholders right now (before running above code):
1
2
3
4
5
6

example of the placeholders right now (after running above code): 
1
0
0
0
0
0

what i want (before running above code):
1
2
3
4
5
6

what i want (after running above code):
1
1
2
3
4
5

(sorry if this makes no sense, im trying my best to explain :( )

Comment: Can you share your `HTML` please ?

Comment: @UgoT. i edited the question :)

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more what are you trying to achieve, I don't really understand.

Comment: @UgoT. edited again... sorry if its hard to understand, im trying my best

Comment: Ok I got it, but when you say `elements`, you talk about the inputs of the snippet (email1, taskproxy ...) right ?

Comment: @UgoT. i mean the #taskid element

Comment: All right, I've edited my answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(this).nextAll('div').each(function() {
    // $(this) refers to each div in the array collected by nextAll()
    return $(this).find('#taskid').attr('placeholder', ((parseInt($(this)
        .find('#taskid').attr('placeholder')) - 1).toString()));
});
```

For better readability:

```
$(this).nextAll('div').each(function() {
    let phText= parseInt($(this).find('#taskid').attr('placeholder') - 1).toString();

    return $(this).find('#taskid').attr('placeholder', phText);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood what you try to do, this code should do what you want :

```js
var pl = parseInt($("input[name='taskid']").first().attr('placeholder'));
$("input[name='taskid']").each(function() {
    $(this).attr('placeholder', pl--);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="i0HYh" class="task" select="yes" style="background-color: rgb(240, 239, 255);">
  <input type="text" name="taskid" placeholder="1" readonly="" id="taskid">
</div>

<div id="i0HYh" class="task" select="yes" style="background-color: rgb(240, 239, 255);">
  <input type="text" name="taskid" placeholder="1" readonly="" id="taskid">
</div>
```

For the example I've cleaned the useless inputs.

So it iterates through all the inputs and set as placeholder value of the `#taskId` placeholder value - 1.